# Azure mobile service scale questions

Tags: azure, scale, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure mobile service, and facing the following questions:

1. What’s strategy for auto-scale, I see it can scale by API calls, 
       what’s threshold for scale? For example, for what condition it will
       increase unit from 3 to 5, and how it will decrease unit from 5 to 3 
       when QPS is down? Can I customise the scale by CPU usage or http queue size?
2. The STANDARD mode has maximum 10 units, how can I extend it more than 10 units?
3. For monitoring, how can I customise monitor matrix, and how to send alert like email?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it really depends on your API. Usually I scale by "Http Queue Length". That gives you some indication as to how long users are waiting for response. I find 'the' threshold by running a load test. You set the scaling rules on the app service plan. But, you could start by defining a static scale rule if possible (few instances at night, more during day).

Scale more than 10, you can scale to 20 in the premium tier. If you need more than that, you need to create an app service environment (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-app-service-environment/)

You can add a few alert rules in the portal (like CPU & http queue length) which sends emails. If you want full customization I would look at Application Insights (or other monitoring/logging service).